# Can't get any Facebook APIs working on Android

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk, fbconnect

I'm pulling my hair out here. I've been trying to get any of the Facebook APIs working in my Android app to no avail.

I've tried the official SDK which just gives me LogCat errors such as:

> 04-26 15:27:06.663: DEBUG/Facebook-authorize(5299): Login failed: invalid_key

although this is followed by:

> 04-26 15:27:06.710: DEBUG/FacewebAuthentication(5306): authentication succeeded

I don't know how to make use of the FacewebAuthentication and so the onFacebookError() method is just always called.

This is when I gave up on the official api and decided to try fbrocket.

But after trying to use it with the same code, [FbRocket](http://www.xeomax.net/fbrocket/) gives me:

> facebook server error 104 + incorrect signature

I can't get [FbConnect](http://code.google.com/p/fbconnect-android/) to compile properly in Eclipse.

As for [Easy Facebook Android SDK](http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/), I managed to get it to post to my status ONCE but since then it hasn't been able to do anything and just always reaches the OnError() function.

I just want to be able to post to the wall and maybe leverage the friends either by REST or Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you are seeing are the errors if the App hasn't been configured on the Facebook web site with it's key hash.  Here are the docs from the Facebook web site:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

Something to note, is to be sure to use the correct key hash.  So if you're testing in debug use the command line in the docs above that uses your debug.keystore keys, but once you are ready to push into production you have to use your production signing key in the command:

> keytool -exportcert -alias
>   androiddebugkey -keystore
>   **~/.android/debug.keystore**  | openssl
>   sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Hopefully I'm guessing the source of the problem correctly.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the reply but even if the hash is the problem, I don't know how to fix it, I've been trying to get that working for about the last month.

I've used command prompt (Im on win7), cygwin and tried all the different combinations of -exportcert -export and different passwords to the keystore that everyone is saying but it always comes back with invalid_key, I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

That's when I started looking at those other APIs which don't use the hash and just use the app Secret and APP ID etc but as I said I've ran into problems with all those as well :(

Comment: It looks like you're not the only one fighting this issue.  This post recommends uninstalling the Facebook app on the phone and seeing if the SDK works w/out single sign-on:  https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/191  Some other folks are saying that they can't get the keytool to work on Win7, but works fine on Linux/Mac: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/140  I'm doing dev on a Mac, so I haven't tried generating on Windows.

Comment: Do you have the error message or exception for the OnError() on the Easy Facebook Android SDK?

Comment: Yeah I've read through those people who say it doesn't work on Win that's why I tried Cygwin like they said. Woah! I've got the easy facebook android sdk working now, I had made a mistake and not put a website url in with an index like the EFAS author says to do (my bad!). I've so far got it to log in and post a status, I'll continue to try further! Thanks for all the help Ryan!